# Calling AWS API Gateway from distant webclient using CORS

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

On AWS, I built a Lambda function which is exposed on the web using API Gateway.

Access to the API is secured by Amazon Cognito.

My problem is I can't send a request to this API from a client hosted at *test.mydomain.com*, even after I successfully authenticate on Cognito (thus sending the required token in the request header).

The code I use on my web client to send the request to API Gateway endpoint:

```
function ajaxPost(url, data, callback) {

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url);

req.addEventListener("load", function () {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
        callback(req.responseText);
    } else {
        console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText + " " + url);
    }
});

req.addEventListener("error", function () {
    console.error("URL " + url + " unreachable.");
});

req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", data.get("id-token"));

data = JSON.stringify(data);

req.send(data);
}
```

I enabled CORS on the API method via AWS console, and also on my browser for testing, so cross-domain requests should be allowed.

**EDIT**

After adding Access-Control-Expose-Headers in the API Gateway CORS config, 
the error message I get from the Chrome console is: *"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://XXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/RessourceName. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401"* and I can see *"x-amzn-errortype:UnauthorizedException"* in the OPTIONS response Header.

It's been a few days now, and after looking at every API Gateway tutorials and config, I'm still stucked... Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the `OPTIONS` request work from curl? e.g. `curl -v -X OPTIONS https://...`

Comment: I got the same "401 / Unauthorized" response from Curl... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Apparently, there would be a bug in AWS, where enabling/editing CORS **after** the API has been deployed would do nothing.

See SO response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733680/7717871

I tried creating a new API from AWS Console, enabling CORS at the very beginning of the process, and then deploying the newly created API: it worked.