# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue when GET from API gateway and lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, angular-httpclient

I am using Angular httpclient to issue get to API Gateway, which triggers lambda to get data and return back. From the network diagram, I am seeing the data being returned but I don't receive the data in my handler of the httpclient get, as if an error occured. And I get this error:

Failed to load https://yxalbf1t6l.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/todos: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

I've implemented the CORS header setting on lambda per suggestion from: [API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

And checked on API gateway to have response mapped in OPTIONS from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried chrome cors plugin?

Comment: Did you add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a 200 response header in your **Method Response** config?

Comment: I add that to OPTIONS. In GET, it only let's me add the 200 response header of Access-Control-Allow-Origin but no option to add any value...

Comment: When following AWS guide to CORS setting on API Gateway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html, I actually got errors on the last 4, including setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin on GET.

Comment: installing cors plugin worked. Could somehow explain to me why? I am thinking that browser is blocking the data that came back. So if I serve frontend on AWS s3, I won't have this issue since origin will be the same?

Answer (score 0):

On my side, even thought API Gateway generates the CORS headers and OPTIONS method, I still needed to inject the header on my lambda.

Chrome expects to see the same access control headers on every response, and Lambda Proxy integration does not inject thosse.

I simply added a header line to my return message, like:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    'body': json.dumps(message, default=convert_timestamp)
}
```