# Unomi Karaf CXF CORS issue to access REST API

Tags: cxf, apache-karaf, karaf

My Name is Mitesh Jain,
I am new to Unomi.

All installations are done according to this link:

http://unomi.incubator.apache.org/

When I am trying to access the rest api cxs to fetch all the rules, it is showing properly in browser when I browse,
https://localhost:9443/cxs/rules

but when I am trying to access the same using my Angular application to fetch rules using above url, https://localhost:9443/cxs/rules it will make a OPTIONS call and I am getting the error as "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Rest API document here: http://unomi.incubator.apache.org/rest-api-doc/index.html#-1505954579

Please Let me know how to fix this CORS issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is probably a CORS issue. I only see one reference to CORS in the documentation [here](http://unomi.incubator.apache.org/manual/1_3_x/index.html#_javascript) in the Javascript section.

Try using `Content-Type` as `text/plain;charset=UTF-8` in your request header.

This should allow the preflight check to pass, more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).