# AWS Lambda - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, serverless

I have AWS lambda function that I am trying to call from my web app using Axios. It keeps giving the error: 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am using serverless and I have added the cors:true attribute to my function. I have also added:

```
            const response = {
                statusCode:200,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'Ticket received',
                    TableData: data,
                }),
            };
            callback(null, response);
```

I still can't get this issue resolve. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was returning 2 different responses, the one above and an error response. Once I defined the error message to have the headers it then worked fine.

Comment: Please show an example code snippet to help the next person

Comment: const response = {
                    statusCode:500,
                    headers: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        message: 'Failed to add ticket to the database.',
                        error: err
                    }),
                };

                callback(null, response);