# CORS error calling AWS API Gateway from Django

Tags: jquery, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I built a simple RESTful endpoint using AWS Lambda and API gateway. API Gateway has  CORS enabled, and the client is sending the proper headers as described [here](https://medium.com/@peorth/using-jquery-to-access-a-aws-api-gateway-cors-afa11fd27f2a)

The client app was built in Django and uses JQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: baseUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

Also, the Lambda function itself returns the following payload:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
    'body': json.dumps(json_response)
}
```

Chrome is still throwing a CORS error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Most browsers will send a "preflight" OPTIONS request to the endpoint, if this response contains the correct CORS headers will then send the actual request. You need to configure your endpoint to send the correct CORS headers for OPTIONS requests https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: Thanks! The OPTIONS method is already returning proper CORS headers though: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Try doing "Enable CORS" from Actions menu. It'll add an OPTIONS method. Post doing this, follow the following link. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell if your question was answered based on the comments, but you may be missing the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header.

```
{
    "headers" : {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : True,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'                        
    },
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body"  : json.dumps(json_response),
}
```

For this to work, you have to be using LAMBDA_PROXY integration on the API Gateway endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for all responses. Unfortunately I had enabled CORS from the Action menu already, which also created the OPTIONS method. I left the default options and deployed the API to dev. As suggested, I tried adding the Access-Control-Allow-Headers option in the Lambda function response and that didn't seem to work. Given how popular Lambda, API Gateway and Django are I was hoping this was a common problem with a common solution. If not then I'll just keep at it and update this post when I find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Under Gateway Responses, edit the Default 4xx settings and add the Response Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'

Note: once I did that I got a `{ "message" : "forbidden" }` response from the API, I needed to add headers to the API call in JQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: baseUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: { "x-api-key": apiKey },
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```