# Fetch returns nothing

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I'm doing an API with aws lambda and API gateway, but when I make a request with fetch it returns nothing and gives me "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" message

I tried to use curl and other website to do this request and the answer was

`{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST"},"body":"oi"}`

And that is what I expected, but using fetch in a js code it returns me the error:
 `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"`

And Access-Control-Allow-Origin is already in header of response

The lambda code:

```
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST"
        },
        body: "oi"
    })
}
```

The fetch code:

```
fetch('URL', {
    method: 'POST',
})
.then((oi) => oi.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript code get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because i already have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in my response header

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: I tried that solutions and nothing worked, and with curl works, so I think maybe is a problem with the way I did my fetch request, but I don't know what is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem going in aws console in API gateway and setting the headers there instead of just in the code

Comment: Please, could you check it as the preferred answer in order for others to know it is already solved?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information this is hard to diagnose, but I would assume you need to enable CORS on your AWS lambda function. Without seeing some of the lambda code its hard to give you any help.

Comment: I did just a test code
`exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"POST"
        },
        body: "oi"
    })
}`

Comment: What is the trigger for your lambda?

Comment: I use API gateway to call it with a request

Comment: Follow this documentation to make sure that CORS is allowed on the API Gateway
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I did this all, enable cors in API gateway and put the headers in the response the problem of this is when I use a sniffer to see the return, the function do not return me nothing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sniffer. Have you tried the same request using curl or an app like Postman?

Comment: CORS always seems to be a headache. I setup a test lambda and enabled cors and it seems to work for me I did notice that I had to enable CORS on the resource itself. not just the method. Also, your lambda is allowing CORS on a POST request but your fetch is making a GET request