# AWS Python CORS header

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I'm trying to use Amazon Textract but upon my API call it says `allow-access-origin-header not present` and makes the API not work. I have taken steps to see that the API itself does work but I can't use this to deploy to customers who want to use the OCR. Is there a python package or maybe a way to make it work?

- I have tested with disable CORS chrome plugin
- I have disabled CORS on chrome to test it
- I have reconfigured API Gateway
- I have added the headers to my json response on AWS Lambda

It is basically a browser problem so how do I add this header to it.

Comment: This is not a Textract issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header/59081762#59081762

Comment: thanks, i will try this now

Answer (score 1):

First install this package

```
$ pip install -U flask-cors
```

then import it to your app.py and implement it like this

```
...
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
...
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/api/something", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def something():
    return Response('{"something":"something else"}', status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: It's an API that is hosted on AWS lambda and API Gateway. It is a react is application. So it has no flask. The only python it has is the API