# AWS API Gateway : CORS and Empty Event Object

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have been struggling with setting up AWS API Gateway to pass Query string parameters to my Lambda function.

If I set to API to use Lambda proxy integration, I get a CORS error at the Web client

```
[index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://g2kza1o79f.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/gettest8' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]
```

( - even when I have set the API with CORS enabled.

If I set the API to not use Lambda proxy integration, and CORS enabled, the API call works (no CORS error), but the event object received in my Lambda function is empty( hence no query string parameters).
In both cases I am using the GET method.
I can see in the Method Response Header the Access-Control-Allow-Origin option is present, but cannot access the Integration Response

**Question**: How can I set-up my API to pass query string parameters through to my Lambda function without getting the CORS error?  I will also be wanting to set up APIs for  POST requests to other Lambda functions.

Comment: Just for clarity. I was not clear in the Lambda Proxy integration set up. I have checked the Method Response and Integration Response areas for the OPTIONS Method, and Access-control-allow/origin/methods are all present.  Could it me that the CORS error message is caused by something else?

Comment: Does this answer brings any sense ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew

Comment: ThanksTraycho Ivanov - your suggested link gave more information about manually setting up QueryString mappings - which I have tried, but still struggled with getting CORS working as well. There may be some kind of hybrid answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to First Enable CORS Then Deploy API.

A good thread could be found here.
[API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Thank again. After reading through the link you provided and applying a change I seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: The fix(at least for me) was to add the appropriate header information ( Access-Allow-Origin etc)  in the return response in my Lambda function. Not very need , but if it works I can live with it.  I still have to set up POST request APIs but hoping the fix still works for them