# AWS - How to enable CORS for Lambda Function

Tags: go, aws-lambda, cors, aws-serverless

I'm trying to enable `CORS` for a Lambda function written in Go and below are my configuration and code.

Here's my SAM config...

```
  AuthBindApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowMethods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
        AllowHeaders: "'X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Referer,User-Agent,Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn

  AuthBindFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/auth/bind
      Handler: bind
      Runtime: go1.x
      Tracing: Active
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref AuthInfoTable
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action: "cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity"
              Resource: "*"
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /auth/bind
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref AuthBindApi
            Auth:
              Authorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Options:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /auth/bind
            Method: OPTIONS
            RestApiId: !Ref AuthBindApi
```

... and here's my lambda:

```
func handler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    ...

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        Headers: map[string]string{
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":  "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST,OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Referer,User-Agent,Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        },
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
    }, nil
}
```

I'va also tried to specify all possible HTTP methods... but I always get the following error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://lc5zxsnfg5.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/bind' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've been struggling for 2 days now and any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you redeploy the API?

Comment: Yes sure, I did.

Comment: I had a similar issue previously, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header).

Comment: My undestanding, API gateway will be the main entry point for this lambda and in API gateway you need to enable cors.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working configuration:

```
  AuthBindApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowMethods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
        AllowHeaders: "'X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Referer,User-Agent,Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn

  AuthBindFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/auth/bind
      Handler: bind
      Runtime: go1.x
      Tracing: Active
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref AuthInfoTable
        - Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action: "cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity"
              Resource: "*"
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /auth/bind
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref AuthBindApi
            Auth:
              Authorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
```

Don't ask me why... but putting all the http methods in `AllowMethods` did the trick:

`AllowMethods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"`