# AWS CORS problem CLOUDFRONT <> APIGATEWAY

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I am struggling with the CORS error.

- I've deployed a backend using APIGATEWAY. It works properly via POSTMAN at the https://APIGATEWAY_URL
- I've deployed a web app using CLOUDFRONT, and it works too, if I open the https://CLOUDFRONT_URL from the browser.

**PROBLEM**

The web app requests are blocked because of the CORS Problem.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[APIGATEWAY_URL]' from origin ' [CLOUDFRONT_URL]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Am I missing some configurations?

Thanks for help

Comment: please review this answer:
[API Gateway CORS: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190615/api-gateway-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to do 2 things in order to fix this CORS issue. I was using **Amazon API Gateway REST API** with **Lambda** using **Proxy integration**.

1. First, you need to configure your **API Gateway** resource to implement an `OPTIONS` method that can respond to the `OPTIONS` preflight request with at least the following response headers mandated by the Fetch standard:

   - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
   - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
   - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

   And this is how, I did it for one of my applications.

   [image]
2. Second thing, if you are doing the **proxy integration**, then your backend is also responsible for returning the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers for all other requests of different types including `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` except `OPTIONS` (since OPTIONS is already handled by the API Gateway).

   For me, it was a **.NET Lambda** function, so I did something like this.

   ```cs
   builder.Services.AddCors(item =>
   {
       item.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", builder =>
       {
           builder.WithOrigins("https://abcd.cloudfront.net") 
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
       });
   });
   ```

You can find more details here - [Enabling CORS for a REST API resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

Comment: HI
I am using API Gateway HTTP API and The backend is implementing the CORS.

The APIGATEWAY_URL and CLOUDFRONT_URL have been generated by the services respectively, they are not linked to a 'proper' domain name.
Thanks.

Comment: Then you have to implement it at API Gateway level also. Are you using CDK or SAM to provision those resources? If yes, you have to make changes there as well to enable CORS support.

Comment: Oh, the solution I provide is for REST API, not for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CDK Script for the AWS example PAM application. This app successfully invokes an API Gateway endpoints using a React app that uses Cloud Front. This app demonstrates how to succesfully set up this configuration.

[image]

Backend is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/pam_source_files

CDK/Front end is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/cdk/photo_asset_manager

Comment: I'll look at the script thanks.

I am wondering if the problem is occurring because the APIGATEWAY_URL and CLOUDFRONT_URL domains are different.