How to add CORS header to response for Swagger UI
I'm getting unable to fetch message in Swagger UI when I'm calling the below AWS API gateway URL via Swagger UI docs locally. The CORS has been enabled on the server, however it's only erroring out on Swagger UI. The same Curl req is executing fine locally.

Below is the message I see in developer tools. I'm very new to Swagger and would like to know how can I set up the CORS in the response header.

Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/GetEmployees' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: API's
  description: >-
    REST API's for abc
  contact:
    name: ABC
    email: ABC
  version: "1.0.0"
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost:8080/"
tags:
  - name: Employees     
    description: Get Employees info 
paths:
  /Employees:
    get:
      description: Get Employee info 
      summary: Get Employee.
      tags:
      - Employees
      security:
      - basicAuth:
        - '[]'
      operationId: GetEmployees
      parameters:
      - name: EmpNbr
        in: query
        description: Employee ID(Example:0123456789)
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: DateofJoin
        in: query
        description: Input DateofJoin(Example:mmddyyyy(01012023))
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
components:
  schemas:
    Employeewithroot:
      properties:
        Employee:
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
          type: array
          x-go-name: Employees
    Employees:
      properties:
        EmpNbr:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DateofJoin:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptId:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        DeptName:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/NullString'
        x-go-package: pkg/model
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header 

Added the steps to the question.
Tried adding header like the below but swagger.yaml is getting invalid.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Employees'
                headers:
                  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                    type: 'string'  


Is CORS enabled in your API Gateway?

Yes, The CORS is enabled on the server. I was playing around making some tweaks and now I get "405 Method Not Allowed" with fetch failed in the swagger ui, however the curl command is running fine locally. Any idea what's the cause? I've been googling and trying to understand if there is any thing that I could do on my side other than tweaking the server settings.

headers is a sibling to content
responses:
        '200':
          description: OK.
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: 'string'  
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/VisitLimitHdr'
                

Setting this in the OpenAPI doesn't do anything though, This is only describing how the response will be returned. CORS needs to be enabled at the server

The CORS is enabled on the server. I was playing around and now I get "405 Method Not Allowed" with fetch failed in the swagger ui, however the curl command is running fine locally. Any idea what's the cause? I've been googling and trying to understand if there is any thing that I could do on my side other than tweaking the server settings.

Does the actual curl output have the access-control-allow-origin: * in the response headers?   If it does, I'm not sure what else you can do. The browser should pick it up and allow the request.  It's possible the endpoint you may be calling doesn't match where you set the cors header.  But that usually won't reply with the cors error.

The check marks on the gateway UI don't mean the changes were deployed. You might try replying it again to verify the changes were enabled

Try this answer or the one below it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860809/8564731

No I don't see access-control-allow-origin: * when I run the curl locally. However, this is set up on openapi.yaml. Also. I see the below in the swagger ui under the response section along with unable to fetch. I tried to fix certain things on my code and now I'm seeing 403 forbidden error though the key used is accurate. Even on postman, it's working with the same call. Headers:
Name Description Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  string
Access-Control-Allow-Methods  string
Access-Control-Allow-Headers  string

If the response from the curl call doesn't include that header, it's not setup correctly

Where do we add cors headers for the curl to show on the ui? I've added below in api code for every endpoint. func GetEmployees(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length, ETag, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT")
}

And it's still not showing up. Do I need to add in swagger ui index.html?
