# Using the AWS API Gateway SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use the AmzaonWebService Api Gateway SDK for Javascript without success.

I've all the time the console error message : "Access Control Allow origin missing"

This is how I do:

```
  dataFactory.setConfig = function() {
        var config = {
          accessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // AWS Access KEY ID
          secretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx', // AWS Secret Key ID
          sessionToken: dataFactory.getCognitoCredentials().idToken.jwtToken,
          region: 'eu-west-1',
          apiKey: undefined,
          defaultContentType: 'application/json',
          defaultAcceptType: 'application/json'
        };
        return config
      }
      var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(dataFactory.setConfig());

      dataFactory.getAll = function() {
        var params = {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          }
        }

        apigClient.allGet(params).then(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
          return res
        }).catch(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
        })
      };
```

This is how I'm getting the credentials:

```
  dataFactory.getCognitoCredentials = function() {
    var res;
    var poolData = {
      UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxxx',
      ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    if (cognitoUser != null) {
      cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
        if (err) {
          alert(err);
          return;
        }
        res = session
      });
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [S3 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Hi @Jamey, can you tell me how you using the aws API GW SDK ?

Comment: Hi @JakyChane, I'm afraid I don't know any Javascript, but I noticed in the link I posted that several people with the same issue as you had found a solution to that specific problem in the bucket properties. Did you look at the first answer?

Comment: I'm not working with S3 bucket I'm working with API Gateway..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325009/aws-api-gateway-endpoint-gives-cors-error-when-post-from-static-site-on-s3

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the CORS headers on API Gateway's response and an OPTION method as a pre-flight method. I have an example swagger file which has CORS setup. You might want to take a look.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Your first API with Amazon API Gateway. This is a sample API that integrates via HTTP with our demo Pet Store endpoints",
    "title": "PetStore"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pets"
        ],
        "description": "PetStore HTML web page containing API usage information",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "text/html"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Type": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Media type of request"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Content-Type": "'text/html'"
              },
              "responseTemplates": {
                "text/html": "<html>\n    <head>\n        <style>\n        body {\n            color: #333;\n            font-family: Sans-serif;\n            max-width: 800px;\n            margin: auto;\n        }\n        </style>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Welcome to your Pet Store API</h1>\n        <p>\n            You have succesfully deployed your first API. You are seeing this HTML page because the <code>GET</code> method to the root resource of your API returns this content as a Mock integration.\n        </p>\n        <p>\n            The Pet Store API contains the <code>/pets</code> and <code>/pets/{petId}</code> resources. By making a <a href=\"/$context.stage/pets/\" target=\"_blank\"><code>GET</code> request</a> to <code>/pets</code> you can retrieve a list of Pets in your API. If you are looking for a specific pet, for example the pet with ID 1, you can make a <a href=\"/$context.stage/pets/1\" target=\"_blank\"><code>GET</code> request</a> to <code>/pets/1</code>.\n        </p>\n        <p>\n            You can use a REST client such as <a href=\"https://www.getpostman.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Postman</a> to test the <code>POST</code> methods in your API to create a new pet. Use the sample body below to send the <code>POST</code> request:\n        </p>\n        <pre>\n{\n    \"type\" : \"cat\",\n    \"price\" : 123.11\n}\n        </pre>\n    </body>\n</html>"
              }
            }
          },
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "type": "mock"
        }
      }
    },
    "/pets": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pets"
        ],
        "summary": "List all pets",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "type",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "The type of pet to retrieve",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "page",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Page number of results to return.",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Pets"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "URI that may access the resource"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestParameters": {
            "integration.request.querystring.page": "method.request.querystring.page",
            "integration.request.querystring.type": "method.request.querystring.type"
          },
          "uri": "http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/petstore/pets",
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "httpMethod": "GET",
          "type": "http"
        }
      },
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "pets"
        ],
        "operationId": "CreatePet",
        "summary": "Create a pet",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "NewPet",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/NewPet"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/NewPetResponse"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "URI that may access the resource"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              }
            }
          },
          "uri": "http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/petstore/pets",
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "httpMethod": "POST",
          "type": "http"
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "URI that may access the resource"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request."
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'POST,GET,OPTIONS'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              }
            }
          },
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "type": "mock"
        }
      }
    },
    "/pets/{petId}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pets"
        ],
        "summary": "Info for a specific pet",
        "operationId": "GetPet",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "The id of the pet to retrieve",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "URI that may access the resource"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestParameters": {
            "integration.request.path.petId": "method.request.path.petId"
          },
          "uri": "http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/petstore/pets/{petId}",
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "httpMethod": "GET",
          "type": "http"
        }
      },
      "options": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "The id of the pet to retrieve",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            },
            "headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "URI that may access the resource"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request."
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'GET,OPTIONS'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
              }
            }
          },
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "type": "mock"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Pets": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
      }
    },
    "Empty": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "NewPetResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "pet": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },
    "NewPet": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/PetType"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },
    "PetType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "dog",
        "cat",
        "fish",
        "bird",
        "gecko"
      ]
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-documentation": {
    "version": "v2.1",
    "createdDate": "2016-11-17T07:03:59Z",
    "documentationParts": [
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "API"
        },
        "properties": {
          "info": {
            "description": "Your first API with Amazon API Gateway. This is a sample API that integrates via HTTP with our demo Pet Store endpoints"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "METHOD",
          "method": "GET"
        },
        "properties": {
          "tags": [
            "pets"
          ],
          "description": "PetStore HTML web page containing API usage information"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "METHOD",
          "path": "/pets/{petId}",
          "method": "GET"
        },
        "properties": {
          "tags": [
            "pets"
          ],
          "summary": "Info for a specific pet"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "METHOD",
          "path": "/pets",
          "method": "GET"
        },
        "properties": {
          "tags": [
            "pets"
          ],
          "summary": "List all pets"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "METHOD",
          "path": "/pets",
          "method": "POST"
        },
        "properties": {
          "tags": [
            "pets"
          ],
          "summary": "Create a pet"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "PATH_PARAMETER",
          "path": "/pets/{petId}",
          "method": "*",
          "name": "petId"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "The id of the pet to retrieve"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "QUERY_PARAMETER",
          "path": "/pets",
          "method": "GET",
          "name": "page"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Page number of results to return."
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "QUERY_PARAMETER",
          "path": "/pets",
          "method": "GET",
          "name": "type"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "The type of pet to retrieve"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "REQUEST_BODY",
          "path": "/pets",
          "method": "POST"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Pet object that needs to be added to the store"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "RESPONSE",
          "method": "*",
          "statusCode": "200"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Successful operation"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "RESPONSE_HEADER",
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "statusCode": "200",
          "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the request."
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "RESPONSE_HEADER",
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "statusCode": "200",
          "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Method or methods allowed when accessing the resource"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "RESPONSE_HEADER",
          "method": "*",
          "statusCode": "200",
          "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "URI that may access the resource"
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "RESPONSE_HEADER",
          "method": "GET",
          "statusCode": "200",
          "name": "Content-Type"
        },
        "properties": {
          "description": "Media type of request"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```